# Why the when playing animation state it's executing the play twice in a row instead once?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script is attached to empty gameobject

At this line i'm using the mouse left button to fire a bullet one time.
If i'm using a break point it will shot one bullet once. but if i'm not using a break point it will shot two bullets in a row one after the other.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;

public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CinemachineVirtualCamera cmf;

    [Header("Main")]
    public Rigidbody bulletPrefab;
    public float launchForce = 700f;
    public bool automaticFire = false;
    public float bulletDestructionTime;
    public bool go = false;

    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Slow Down")]
    public float maxDrag;
    public float bulletSpeed;
    public bool bulletsSlowDown = false;
    public bool overAllSlowdown = false;
    [Range(0, 1f)]
    public float slowdownAll = 1f;

    public List<Transform> firePoints = new List<Transform>();
    public Animator anim;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (anim != null)
        {
            anim.SetBool("Shooting", true);
        }
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (overAllSlowdown == true)
        {
            Time.timeScale = slowdownAll;
        }

        if (firePoints.Count > 0))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < firePoints.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
                {
                    anim.SetTrigger("Shoot");
                    
                }
                
                if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
                {
                    cmf.enabled = false;

                }

                if (go)
                {
                    LaunchProjectile(firePoints[i]);
                    go = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void LaunchProjectile(Transform firePoint)
    {
        Rigidbody projectileInstance = Instantiate(
            bulletPrefab,
            firePoint.position,
            firePoint.rotation);

        projectileInstance.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);

        cmf.enabled = true;
        cmf.Follow = projectileInstance.transform;
        cmf.LookAt = projectileInstance.transform;

        projectileInstance.AddForce(new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * launchForce);

        if (bulletsSlowDown == true)
        {
            if (projectileInstance != null)
            {
                StartCoroutine(AddDrag(maxDrag, bulletSpeed, projectileInstance));
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator AddDrag(float maxDrag, float bulletSpeed, Rigidbody rb)
    {
        if (rb != null)
        {
            float current_drag = 0;

            while (current_drag < maxDrag)
            {
                current_drag += Time.deltaTime * bulletSpeed;
                rb.drag = current_drag;
                yield return null;
            }

            rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
            rb.drag = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This script is attached to my player with animator and i'm using this method to reference event i added to animation in the animator controller. when the event happens the variable bool flag go is set to true.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ThrowObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Shooting shooting;

    public void ThrowEvent()
    {
        shooting.go = true;
    }
}
```

This is a screenshot of the animator controller.

I added a new state name Throwing with two transitions from and to the Grounded state.
The Grounded state is playing idle animation.

In the transition from the Grounded to the Throwing i added a condition name Shoot type trigger.
In the transition from the Throwing state to the Grounded there is no any conditions.

[image: Animation controller]

Answer (score 0):

Afaik animator triggers are **stackable**!

So since you call this in a `for` loop it might happen that it adds multiple triggers at once but each transition only consumes one at a time!

What I ended up using in combination with triggers in an animator is this script

```
public class AnimatorTriggerResetter : StateMachineBehaviour
{
    override public void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        foreach(var p in animator.parameters)
        {
            if (p.type == AnimatorControllerParameterType.Trigger)
            {
                animator.ResetTrigger(p.name);   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

attach this to no specific state at all but directly to the `Basic` layer of your `AnimatorController` itself => It is called for each and every state that is entered => resets all existing triggers.

[image]

---

In your specific case though, why not rather pull the general calls out of the loop and rather make it

```
if (firePoints.Count > 0 && go)
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        anim.SetTrigger("Shoot");               
    }
            
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        cmf.enabled = false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < firePoints.Count; i++)
    {
        LaunchProjectile(firePoints[i]); 
    }

    go = false;
}
```